# Pimp my VM (about performance and jitting)

Tags: interpreter, jit, vm-implementation

for one of my programs I needed a scripting language to dynamically change the world (unit ai, world generation etc), So I wrote a Compiler for a rather basic language (simple objects without inheritance, 1d arrays, 32 bit ints/floats, strings) which also uses reference counting for garbage collection. The Compiler outputs stack based bytecode.

My problem now is that my VM isnt efficient enough (it actually runs 15-30 times slower than unoptimised C). Its a really simple VM which implements decoding with a giant SWITCH-CASE block.

the vm code looks like this:

```
switch(*ip++)
    case ADD:
        ...
        break;
    case SUB:
        ...
        break;
```

So my question is if it is possible to recompile my scripts to x86 assembler and execute them them at runtime. (I think thats what JIT compilers do). I googled a lot but I didn´t found any code samples for example to send x86 code to the processor. If anyone has links to tutorials that explain how to build better VM´s I would be very happy.

Comment: A technique more sophisticated than the switch threading you're using is inline threading, paper here http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.23.8829 blog here http://blog.mozilla.org/dmandelin/2008/08/27/inline-threading-tracemonkey-etc/ , jamvm uses this technique.